# Можно ли использовать C# 7.0 в VS старее 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Можно ли использовать C# 7.0 в VS старее 2017?

Comment: Можно. Осталось узнать, как :)

Comment: Посмотри тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @AresGod, находил этот ответ, но там пишут про ложные срабатывания проверки ошибок

Comment: Именно так оно и работает - сбилдить можно, но хватает ложных ошибок и подсказки иногда неудачные.

Comment: @Monk. хм... Неужели это все вшито в VS? Ведь как-то же можно доустановить другие языки, которые имеют альтернативный синтаксис.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Ну это специальное ограничение, чтобы обновлялись до новой студии. А в чём проблема обновиться? Новая студия быстрей и удобней. Если что есть Community версия, если платную приобрести или установить проблема.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461407/1548895

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov сидим со старой версией на сервере, на котором у нас есть права) Интересные корпоративные политики. Обновиться не можем по ряду подобных причин.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Вольный перевод [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048660/1548895).</sub>

Вы можете заменить компилятор, установленный с Visual Studio, на C# 7-совместимую версию с помощью установки Nuget-пакета [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/):

> Ссылка на этот пакет заставит проект компилироваться с помощью специфической версии компиляторов C# и Visual Basic, содержащихся в пакете, независимо от версии установленной в системе.

Нет никаких указаний на странице Nuget-пакета поддерживается ли он официально Visual Studio 2015. Мои нетщательные тесты свидетельствуют, что он работает, но не безболезненно — код C# 7 компилируется, но подчёркнут красной волнистой линией, которая показывает синтаксические ошибки:
[image: Screenshot]Обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет также установить  Nuget-пакет [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) чтобы использователь новые C# 7 возможности кортежей (value tuple).